# php displaying API (rest) info in a for each loop

Tags: php, api, rest

Well I have been successfully displaying API stats from Riot games...However this one is very weird. And i Cannot for the life of me get the results to entries, like leaguePoints, wins, isfreshblood. stuff like that

this is the data i am scraping from.

```
{"29283170": [
{
"queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"name": "Annie's Blades",
"entries": [{
"leaguePoints": 52,
"isFreshBlood": false,
"isHotStreak": false,
"division": "II",
"isInactive": false,
"isVeteran": false,
"playerOrTeamName": "Cleland",
"playerOrTeamId": "29283170",
"wins": 5
}],
"tier": "BRONZE"
},
{
"queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
"name": "Blitzcrank's Avengers",
"tier": "CHALLENGER"
}
]}
```

I can get the tier, no problem. i have tried MANY different methods
below are just a few i have tried *sigh* (THIS IS JUST THE FOR EACH LOOP)

Attempt #1

```
$objs = json_decode($response3, true);
foreach ($objs['entries'] as $val)
{
$league=$val['tier'];
$pts=$val['leaguePoints'];
$wins=$val['wins'];
}
```

Attempt #2
*note $myid is my league of legends player id a.k.a

```
{"29283170": [
```

So this was fun. but doable by the below.

```
$objs = json_decode($response3, true);
foreach ($objs[$myid] as $val)
{
$league=$val['tier'];
$pts=$val['entries']['leaguePoints'];
$wins=$val['entries']['wins'];
}
```

now with the above i can get the tier, which is outside the entries block.
but i cannot access any information like leaguepoints or wins.
I have been trying for a few days now, any help..would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you var_dump the $response....that should show you the true PHP structure

Comment: You have a JSON object within an array of 1 element (The object is the only element in entries.
you should try $val[0]->leaguePoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access it as array elements, as [json_decode()](http://us.php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php), with true as last parameter , associative array is returned, you can just to:

```
$myid = "29283170";
foreach ($objs[$myid] as $val)
{ 
    $league=$val['tier'];
    if(array_key_exists('entries', $val)) {
        echo $val['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo $val['entries'][0]['wins'];
    }
}
```